# Redmine bug reporter to add watchers?

Tags: redmine

Is it possible and how to give permissions to issue Reporters to add watchers to the issues they open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a role option.  Under Administration | Roles, edit the role (I'm assuming you have a role named "Reporters"?).  Enable the "Add Watchers" option, within the Issue tracking section.